# Mouse cursor on multiple screens with different PPI

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution, mouse-cursor

I'm using a 4K display along with a Full HD display with both almost the same physical size and it brings some mouse cursor problems to me working with it on the default Windows settings.

As the **mouse movement speed** depends on the pixels, it's very slow on the 4K display and very fast on the Full HD display.
Is there a windows setting or application to move the mouse depending on the visible distance and not the pixels?

Another problem is the **virtual wall** between the screens I can't move the cursor from the upper half of the 4K screen to the Full HD screen:

[image: Windows creen settings]

How is it possible to virtually stretch the cursor transition area of the Full HD screen to the one of the 4K monitor?

The smallest problem, nevertheless painful, is the **cursor size** which varies between the screens. Is there a way to keep the same visual mouse size on both screens?

Comment: Good question. Maybe you should open the feedback app and file a bug for this. [Relationship between mouse DPI, screen resolution and screen size](http://superuser.com/q/769955/241386)

Comment: Try [Non Stick Mouse](http://www.jawfin.net/?page_id=143).

Comment: @harrymc The question is not about the Windows Snap Assist, but about the problems which emerge from different screen resolutions.

Comment: This app is not about Snap.

Comment: Related Questions:
http://superuser.com/questions/980193/windows-10-dual-monitor-ppi-issues
http://superuser.com/questions/826880/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-mouse-pointer-speed-for-individual-monitors

Comment: Regarding the "Wall" between the two monitors: http://superuser.com/questions/973452/how-to-make-monitor-edges-match-on-windows-7

Comment: It appears (I can confirm this) that Microsoft has finally fixed the mouse speed issue in Windows 10 Insider Preview build 16273 so most probably the fix will be in Fall Creators Update (2017).

Comment: If someone has the link to the feedback hub question for this, please share here, I won't mind upvoting the issue there as well!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Virtual wall

- [LittleBigMouse](https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse) fixes the virtual wall problem in its current version, as Flexo013 pointed out in [his answer](https://superuser.com/a/1301681/368751)
- [Continuous Mouse](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/continuous-mouse/9p6nts4k5425) ($3.79 on ms store) also fixes the issue by allowing to set up Mouse transitions between the monitors. - thanks to mtooling for the link
- [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) provides an [option for skipping the Virtual wall](https://superuser.com/a/973468/368751) in it's paid Pro version - thanks to Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 for the link
- There is a study published by Microsoft in 2004: [Mouse ether: accelerating the acquisition of targets across multi-monitor displays](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=73728). It finds that mouse ether improved participants’ performance on a target acquisition task across two screens running at different resolutions by up to 28%. Unfortunately, the mentioned application **Mouse Ether** isn't available for download.
  [image: Mouse ether: accelerating the acquisition of targets across multi-monitor displays]

### Cursor speed

It [appears](https://github.com/sandord/DpiGonzales/issues/20) that Microsoft has finally fixed the mouse speed issue in Windows 10 Insider Preview build 16273 so most probably the fix will be in Fall Creators Update (2017). It is activated by changing the scaling of a screen.

There were three projects which address the cursor speed problem on multiple screens with different resolutions.

- **DpiGonzales** [on github](https://github.com/sandord/DpiGonzales) which works very well on my system - thanks to Sandor Drieënhuizen for developping the tool and for sharing the link
- There is a project called **LittleBigMouse** [on github](https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse), which is in alpha state and not stable on my system.
- The most configurable program I've found is **Custom Screen Speed** [on its developers website](http://shanedidona.com/programspage), but the configuration has to be set manually and it is not stored. Therefore it has to be reconfigured at each system start.
  [image: Custom Screen Speed]

### Cursor Size

No projects found yet

Comment: The cursor speed problem (and the lack of updates on the Custom Screen Speed program) inspired me to fix the problem myself. My take on the problem currently doesn't require any configuration. It dynamically adapts pointer speed on higher DPI displays. You can download it here https://github.com/sandord/DpiGonzales. Community contributions are very welcome!

Comment: Unfortunately the Gonzales app does not work with my Win 10 Precision touchpad.

Comment: Cursor speed should be fixed since 2017 by Microsofts Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (2017)

Answer (score 6):

Found this solution, which should at least fix the **virtual wall** problem, on a different [thread](https://superuser.com/a/1142011/), originally from Steve:

> Perhaps LittleBigMouse could help you out? It's an alpha application, but it seems to be focusing on the issue you're having.
>
> Github: https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse
>
> Download (Releases): https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse/releases

I have been using it myself with a 4K UHD monitor and a 1080p Full HD monitor and this does exactly what you want.

As for the **cursor speed**, this can be solved by changing the scaling of the screen within Windows. For example set your 4K display to 200% and your 1080p screen to 100%. Then the cursor size and speed should be the same on both screens.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a dpi issue, not related to windows, see, a 4k moniter has more pixels while a full HD one has less pixels, you either have to get a 'on-the-go dpi adjustable' mouse like a razer perhaps, or use the windows inbuilt mouse speed option in main.cpl (tho it will increase the mouse speed on the full HD screen also), and alternatiely the best sollution, a program that sets 'custom desities' on two different screens. As for the Virtual wall, changing your display size of the FHD display to 200% should work, the bigger mouse pointer would also be solved by this i suppose, I cant tell if the mouse pointer will be solved or not because i use 2 x 1080p displays for gaming.